# setTimeout causing Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, typeerror, cleartimeout

so I'm declaring blank variables outside of functions.

```
//To be Timeouts
var progressionTimer;
var nextTimer; 
var cycleTimer;
```

and then within functions

```
progressionTimer = setTimout(loadNextFunction, 2000);
progressionTimer();

nextTimer = setTimeout(loadOutsideFunction, 2000);
nextTimer();

//etc
```

however every time one of those declaration is called

```
nextTimer();
```

my console in chrome/firefox/etc fills with this

```
Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function
```

it functions absolutely as intended and clearTimeout works without issue, but the console error is just frustrating me, can anyone solve this without loosing the funcitonality and still having clearTimeout work?

Comment: Because nextTimer isn't a function, it's an id for the timeout which you would pass to clearTimout to clear it.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` returns a handler, an ID that lets you reference the timeout so you can clear it with `clearTimeout`, which is a number.

It **does not** return a function that can be executed, and that is the problem, you're trying to execute the return value of `setTimeout`

```
nextTimer = setTimeout(loadOutsideFunction, 2000);
nextTimer(); // not a function, but a number referencing the timeout ?

clearTimeout(nextTimer); // works just fine
```

Comment: thanks! I was under the impression I had to call the setTimeout. so now I've just deleted the

    nextTimer();

and its all functioning without issue.